# How to decide columns and indexes of Pandas DataFrame created from other object

Tags: python, pandas

When we create a new dataframe from other object, like dict of dict or dict of list, how do we know which labels are columns or indexes.

```
dd = {'one': {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0, 'd': 4.0},
     'two': {'a': 4.0, 'b': 3.0, 'c': 2.0, 'd': 1.0}}
ld = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 20}]

pd1 = pd.DataFrame(dd)
# pd1:
#    one  two
# a  1.0  4.0
# b  2.0  3.0
# c  3.0  2.0
# d  4.0  1.0

pd2 = pd.DataFrame(ld)
# pd2:
#    a   b     c
# 0  1   2   NaN
# 1  5  10  20.0
```

Why the `a`, `b`, `c` are indexes in pd1, but are columns in pd2?

What I understand is the outside labels are columns and inside levels are index if they exist. So the outside labels `one` and `two` in the `dd` are used as columns in pd1 and inside labels `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are used as index. However, `a`, `b` and `c` are used as columns since they are outside labels in ld.

I don't know if this understanding is correct. Is there any counter-example against it or any better explanation about deciding the columns and indexes when creating dataframes?

Comment: I think you need check source code - if input is `dict` is used [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L402) and if list is used another code - [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L351).